# Collect()function error in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am using the "collect()" function on a spark dataframe. But, the command is throwing an error as shown in the attached screenshot. Attaching the screenshot for reference.

Kindly, let me know in case if there is anything wrong in my code.

[image]

Updated Error Message

[image]

Regards,
Mohanraj

Comment: try `csv_df.filter(csv_df['Low'] == 100.0).collect()`

Comment: @RameshMaharjan I didnt work Ramesh. I have already tried it...

Comment: try assigning it to a variable then

Comment: Because of lazy evaluation collect method can sometimes throw error while show method not(show use only to a few rows). Can you upload full text of error.

Comment: @hamzatuna I have updated the error message.

Comment: @RameshMaharjan Ramesh even i have tried to assign it to some variable. But, still the error is prevailing...

Comment: something must be wrong with your jupyter installation as the code works for me in intellij

Comment: Ok @RameshMaharjan Thanks for trying it out....